# Azure AD ADAuthenticationError 15 - unauthorized_client - Application is not supported for this API version

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, adal

I need register my app for using Outlook Calendar API. I created app here: https://apps.dev.microsoft.com. I've got Application Id and Redirect URI. Then I've used following method to get token:

```
[self.context acquireTokenWithResource:resourceID
                              clientId:clientID
                           redirectUri:redirectURI
                       completionBlock:^(ADAuthenticationResult *result) {
                           if (result.status !=AD_SUCCEEDED){
                               completion(result.error);
                           }

                           else{
                               self.accessToken = result.accessToken;
                               self.refreshToken = result.tokenCacheStoreItem.refreshToken;
                               self.familyName = result.tokenCacheStoreItem.userInformation.familyName;
                               self.givenName = result.tokenCacheStoreItem.userInformation.givenName;
                               self.userID = result.tokenCacheStoreItem.userInformation.userId;
                               completion(nil);
                           }
                       }];
```

And got this error:

```
Error with code: 15 Domain: ADAuthenticationErrorDomain ProtocolCode:unauthorized_client Details:AADSTS70001: Application '***' is not supported for this API version.
Trace ID: c5286e11-9fa9-4ddd-96a4-a29ddd6b416c
Correlation ID: c608d556-729b-4cad-80be-24d85f5558d4
Timestamp: 2016-03-14 13:05:11Z. Inner error details: Error Domain=ADAuthenticationErrorDomain Code=15 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (ADAuthenticationErrorDomain error 15.)"
```

Please, help me to register my app correctly

UPDATE:
@dstrockis helped with this problem. But now I have one else:
There https://cocoapods.org/pods/ADALiOS is used method

```
 [authContext acquireTokenWithResource:resourceId
                             clientId:clientId
                          redirectUri:redirectUri
                      completionBlock:^(ADAuthenticationResult *result) {
    if (AD_SUCCEEDED != result.status){
        // display error on the screen
        [self showError:result.error.errorDetails];
    }
    else{
        completionBlock(result.accessToken);
    }
}];
```

But ADALiOS library, 3.0.0-pre3 does not contain this method. I've tried to use

```
- (void)acquireTokenWithScopes:(NSArray*)scopes
          additionalScopes:(NSArray*)additionalScopes
                  clientId:(NSString*)clientId
               redirectUri:(NSURL*)redirectUri
                identifier:(ADUserIdentifier*)identifier
            promptBehavior:(ADPromptBehavior)promptBehavior
           completionBlock:(ADAuthenticationCallback)completionBlock;
```

And I got following error:"Error with code: 17 Domain: ADAuthenticationErrorDomain ProtocolCode:(null) Details:The Application does not have a current ViewController. Inner error details: Error Domain=ADAuthenticationErrorDomain Code=17 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (ADAuthenticationErrorDomain error 17.)"".

Comment: That is the correct method to use. I'll see if I can get our iOS guy to comment on that particular error. You do need to be calling that method in the context of a ViewController, so that adal can pop out a web view to perform authentication.

Comment: @dstrockis, I called it in my View Controller, in ViewDidLoad method
Previous method "acquireTokenWithResource" I also called there and authorization controller was shown

Comment: @dstrockis do you happen to find out anything else about this problem? It actually has been a long row to hoe, so if you or your iOS guy could help, it would be really appreciated:)

Answer (score 1):

you are using the wrong version of the ADALiOS library.  In order to use the v2.0 endpoint (and apps registered at apps.dev.microsoft.com), you will need to use the preview version of the ADALiOS library, 3.0.0-pre3.  See https://cocoapods.org/pods/ADALiOS.  More information about the v2.0 endpoint is available at aka.ms/aaddevv2.

Comment: thank you very much, it helped to solve my problem. But now I have another problem, I added it after UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

For your updated question:

You may want to specify the parent view controller before you call *acquireTokenWithScopes* in case ADAL cannot find your root view controller.

E.g., setting

*context.parentController = self;*

before calling *acquireTokenWithScopes*.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've done it already but it still does not work on iOS7 devices. I have controller, but it does not work because of bad request. On iOS8 and greater devices everything works without context.parentController = self

Comment: there was an exception in the string "if (query && [query containsString:ADAL_ID_VERSION])" in file "ADHelpers.m". I rewrote it depending on iOS version. Then I've seen authorization controller with "Sorry. but we are having trouble signing you in. We received bad request. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid". I put nil instead of this parameter. But got error: "parameter 'scope' is required". On iOS8 and greater devices it works only with 'scopes' nil, but I can't get calendar events because of invalid token.

Comment: I solved problem with iOS7, I had to put in 'scopes' "https://outlook.office.com/Calendars.Read" instead of "https://outlook.office.com/calendars.read"))